# Techniques to measure / picture very low (cryo)temperatures

Tags: temperature, metrology

I am looking for an experimental technique to measure/create a temperature map of a small object (few mm diameter), like in terms of IR camera.

However, all IR-cameras I encountered measured temperatures higher than -20 C, and I would need something around 10K. (With 10K I mean the temperature of the object, not of the camera, as I am aware that some of the IR cameras are cryo-cooled). Are there any IR camera which can do it/ are there any other techniques to perform my task? If not, how low one could still get with existing techniques?

Comment: Not sure how any IR technique would work, considering where the blackbody spectrum would be at T = 10K ?? But experimental physicists seem to work in this realm often, so maybe a question for https://physics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I wrote also there and my question was closed as too little scientific…